# Backend CSV Update Partially Working

Tags: magento-1.9, error, overrides, bug

When i try to `update all products QTY = 0`, Actually its uploading and `successfully uploaded`, and go to `back end QTY column is 0, the terrific error is, stock availability still "in stock",` (`Actually QTY is 0 mean stock availability "Out Of Stock`").

**After i go to individual products just click save button with any changes, shockingly its working, the thing is i did nothing changes, just click save button.**

How can i solve updated not working on Magento version : 1.9.2.3

Comment: You have to set out of stock product when you import product data.

Comment: I need to update my QTY, after import

Comment: Import csv with out of stock value of product.

Comment: i tried bro not working

Comment: add csv column with one single row

Comment: no bro not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47453/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-jeeva-rathinam).